# Is it possible to add jquery link on each nav items

Tags: jquery, wheelnav.js

I need to add jquery class : `<a href="#" class="toggle-link" data-div-id="div1">` for each nav items to launch hidden DIV. Is it possible ?
every nav items must have `class="toggle-link"` . I tried to add it using jquery `.addClass('toggle-link');` but failed

Thanks in advance

```
<div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='0'><a href="#" class="toggle-link" data-div-id="div1">panel1</a></div>
<div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='1'><a href="#" class="toggle-link" data-div-id="div2">panel 2</a></div>
```

Comment: What is the complete jQuery `code` you added? 

Comment: `<a href="#" class="toggle-link" data-div-id="div1">Test panel 1</a> 
<a href="#" class="toggle-link" data-div-id="div2">Test panel 2</a>`

>> Just  ordinary html

Comment: HTML is not jQuery

Comment: "*but failed*" - you failed to add the class, or it didn't do what you were expecting after you added the class?  `toggle-link` sounds like it might have an associated action, eg toggling a link.   Whatever is *using* that class may have already assigned event handlers before you add the class.   Please include all the relevant code and detail what you are *trying* to do.  See [mcve]

Comment: i had tested by adding 2 links in the same page below the wheelnav, to add the class "active"

Jquery:
`   $('#' + linkId).addClass('active');`

The 2 links works but it doesnt work on wheelnav items

I guessed it doesn't have the capabilities to directly work with jquery straight out of the box. Have to edit the JS manually